# Android studio: Unable to create new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded android studio to 2.3 after number of errors I got to compile project but when i try to create new project, nothing happens no error, could anyone tell me why this happening

idea.log:

```
2017-03-21 23:20:15,671 [ 728938]  ERROR - pplication.impl
.LaterInvocator -     Android Studio 2.3  Build #AI-162.3764568 
2017-03-21 23:20:15,671 [ 728938]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator
-  JDK: 1.8.0_45 
2017-03-21 23:20:15,671 [ 728938]  ERROR - pplication.impl
.LaterInvocator - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
2017-03-21 23:20:15,671 [ 728938]  ERROR - pplication.impl.
LaterInvocator -  Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2017-03-21 23:20:15,671 [ 728938]  ERROR - 
pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - OS: Windows 8 
2017-03-21 23:20:15,671 [ 728938]  ERROR - pplication.impl.
LaterInvocator -  Last Action: ShowLog 
2017-03-21 23:20:16,317 [ 729584]   INFO - .diagnostic.
PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 11ms; general 
responsiveness:  ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2017-03-21 23:20:18,160 [ 731427]   INFO - .diagnostic.
PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 1843ms;
general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 

2017-03-21 23:22:42,925 [ 876192]   WARN - 
ctions.AndroidNewProjectAction - Unable to launch New Project Wizard 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle plugin missing from the
offline  Maven repo 
at    com.android.tools.idea.gradle.plugin.AndroidPluginGeneration.getLatestKnownVersion(AndroidPluginGeneration.java:213)
```

and so on

Comment: You surely get some error. Check idea.log or gradle logs

Comment: where is idea.log in android studio

Comment: I am sure a quick search on your favorite search engine could give you the answer about the log location...

Comment: okay there are 3 files idea.log 1, 2 and 3

Comment: This error is showing in idea.log, see updated question

Comment: Now have a look

Comment: have you checked gradle offline in your AS settings?

Comment: no i have not checked

Comment: Its unchecked in the settings

Comment: also its saying gradle

Comment: also its saying gradle plugin missing from the offline maven repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by downloading all the packages also uninstalling AS without uninstalling SDK, also when installing AS keep the internet connection off, hope it help others too, and save from a lot of trouble i faced!

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this bug. After new project wizard nothing happened. I discovered that it was a bug in the project template file.
To fix this issue,

1. Copy the content of this [file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-2.3/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/build.gradle.ftl)
2. Paste it into `{Android Studio installation location}`/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/build.gradle.ftl
3. Restart Android Studio if it's open

Hope it helps someone